# SourceFileLoader fails for relative imports

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

SourceFileLoader from importlib fails specifically when there are relative imports (not absolute ones). How should I specify the parent module so that this doesn't happen.  For example,

```
>>> from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader                                                                                                                                                    
>>> SourceFileLoader('t_sne', 'venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py').load_module()                                                                                               

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-553b4ae077de> in <module>
----> 1 SourceFileLoader('t_sne', 'venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py').load_module()

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in _check_name_wrapper(self, name, *args, **kwargs)

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in load_module(self, fullname)

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in load_module(self, fullname)

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load_module_shim(self, fullname)

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load(spec)

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/PycharmProjects/codemap/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py in <module>
     17 from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
     18 from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
---> 19 from ..neighbors import NearestNeighbors
     20 from ..base import BaseEstimator
     21 from ..utils import check_array

SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I have other reasons for loading modules in this way in the first place, so the solution should allow me to load the module from a file path and deal with relative imports within the file.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar situation.
I loaded the `__init__` files first and then my desired file - adding the namespace too.
This worked for me on `python3.9.8` on a Mac.

DISCLAIMER, I did not run your code nor my provided solution; I ran something similar. You *may* have to load more modules / namespaces depending on what is in those `__init__` files. Also, `load_module` is deprecated in 3.9, but I could not get the non-deprecated options to work. I hope this suggestion gets you closer to a solution!

```py
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

# Add parent init files
SourceFileLoader('sklearn', 'venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py').load_module()
SourceFileLoader('sklearn.manifold', 'venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/__init__.py').load_module()

# Import module that has relative imports in it                                                                    
t_sne = SourceFileLoader('sklearn.manifold.t_sne', 'venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py').load_module()
```